# Benefits of Structured Logging vs basic logging

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, logging

We're building a new app and I'd like to include structured logging. My ideal setup would be something like `Serilog` for our C# code, and `Bunyan` for our JS. These would feed into `fluentd` and then could go out to any number of things, I was thinking initially `elasticsearch + kibana`. We have a MySQL database already, so in the short term I'm more interested in getting Serilog + Bunyan setup and the devs to use it and we can log to MySQL while we take a bit more time bringing in fluentd and the rest.

However, one of our more experienced coders would prefer to just do something like: `log.debug("Disk quota {0} exceeded by user {1}", quota, user);` using `log4net` and then just run select statements against MySQL like: `SELECT text FROM logs WHERE text LIKE "Disk quota";`

That being said, which approach is better and/or what things do we need to consider when choosing the type of logging system?

Comment: I agree with the edits that were made. I'm not so much trying to prove something to someone as I am trying to understand the benefits and difference in structured vs. basic logging. In my mind structured gives us much more flexibility especially in the sources of logs, and how we are then able to display their data. At the point of my understanding, I'm unable to explain why basic logging and searching MySQL is better/worse than structured logging.

Comment: @DTI-Matt serilog's structured logging is just basic logging, only it formats objects that you print to it - something you can do yourself by over-riding ToString very easily. A more important aspect is configuration and management of the log files, not one way of formatting a string over another, another is performance. If the dev wants to use log4net (which is a good logging lib), then your choice of serilog (which looks cool) is one of those "solutions in search of a problem" things.

Comment: @DTI-Matt From looking at serilog it looks very similar to log4net.  log4net handles creating structured logs on config.  You do not need to search the log messages as you can have additional information configured and written to a table. Also configure log4net for fluentd http://www.tipstuff.org/2014/05/config-log4net-send-log-to-elasticsearch-with-fluentd-and-kibana-realtime-and-centralization-part-2.html

Comment: @gbjbaanb Serilog works the same way as log4net when rendering events as text, but if you use a structured format to store logs, it'll associate named properties with the arguments that are passed through (i.e. to support searching/filtering without regex etc.) HTH!

Answer (score 212):

There are two fundamental advances with the *structured* approach that can't be emulated using text logs without (sometimes extreme levels of) additional effort.

### Event Types

When you write two events with **log4net** like:

```
log.Debug("Disk quota {0} exceeded by user {1}", 100, "DTI-Matt");
log.Debug("Disk quota {0} exceeded by user {1}", 150, "nblumhardt");
```

These will produce similar text:

```
Disk quota 100 exceeded by user DTI-Matt
Disk quota 150 exceeded by user nblumhardt
```

But, as far as machine processing is concerned, they're just two lines of different text.

You may wish to find all "disk quota exceeded" events, but the simplistic case of looking for events `like 'Disk quota%'` will fall down as soon as another event occurs looking like:

```
Disk quota 100 set for user DTI-Matt
```

Text logging throws away the information we initially have about the source of the event, and this has to be reconstructed when reading the logs usually with more and more elaborate match expressions.

By contrast, when you write the following two **Serilog** events:

```
log.Debug("Disk quota {Quota} exceeded by user {Username}", 100, "DTI-Matt");
log.Debug("Disk quota {Quota} exceeded by user {Username}", 150, "nblumhardt");
```

These produce similar text output to the log4net version, but behind the scenes, the `"Disk quota {Quota} exceeded by user {Username}"` [message template](https://messagetemplates.org) is carried by both events.

With an appropriate sink, you can later write queries `where MessageTemplate = 'Disk quota {Quota} exceeded by user {Username}'` and get *exactly* the events where the disk quota was exceeded.

It's not always convenient to store the entire message template with every log event, so some sinks hash the message template into a numeric `EventType` value (e.g. `0x1234abcd`), or, you can add an enricher to the logging pipeline to [do this yourself](http://nblumhardt.com/2015/10/assigning-event-types-to-serilog-events/).

It's more subtle than the next difference below, but a massively powerful one when dealing with large log volumes.

### Structured Data

Again considering the two events about disk space usage, it may be easy enough using text logs to query for a particular user with `like 'Disk quota' and like 'DTI-Matt'`.

But, production diagnostics aren't always so straightforward. Imagine it's necessary to find events where the disk quota exceeded was below 125 MB?

With Serilog, this is possible in most sinks using a variant of:

```
Quota < 125
```

Constructing this kind of query from a regular expression *is* possible, but it gets tiring fast and usually ends up being a measure of last resort.

Now add to this an event type:

```
Quota < 125 and EventType = 0x1234abcd
```

You start to see here how these capabilities combine in a straightforward way to make production debugging with logs feel like a first-class development activity.

One further benefit, perhaps not as easy to prevent up front, but once production debugging has been lifted out of the land of regex hackery, developers start to value logs a lot more and exercise more care and consideration when writing them. Better logs -> better quality applications -> more happiness all around.

Comment: i love this answer. very well written and for some reason I cannot explain, keeps me on the edge of my seat.

Answer (score 17):

When you are collecting logs for processing, be it for parsing into some database and/or searching through the processed logs later, using *structured* logging makes some of the processing easier/more efficient.  The parser can take advantage of the known structure (*e.g.* JSON, XML, ASN.1, whatever) and use state machines for parsing, as opposed to regular expressions (which can be computationally expensive (relatively) to compile and execute).  Parsing of free-form text, such as that suggested by your coworker, tends to rely on regular expressions, **and** to rely on that text *not changing*.  This can make parsing free-form text rather fragile (*i.e.* parsing is tightly coupled to the exact text in the code).

Consider also the search/lookup case, *e.g.*:

```
SELECT text FROM logs WHERE text LIKE "Disk quota";
```

`LIKE` conditions require comparisons with every `text` row value; again, this is relatively computationally expensive, *particularly so* when wildcards are used:

```
SELECT text FROM logs WHERE text LIKE "Disk %";
```

With structured logging, your disk-error related log message might look like this in JSON:

```
{ "level": "DEBUG", "user": "username", "error_type": "disk", "text": "Disk quota ... exceeded by user ..." }
```

The fields of this kind of structure can map pretty easily to *e.g.* SQL table column names, which turn means the lookup can be more specific/granular:

```
SELECT user, text FROM logs WHERE error_type = "disk";
```

You can place indexes on the columns whose values you expect to search/lookup frequently, *as long as you don't use `LIKE` clauses for those column values*.  The more you can break down your log message into specific categories, the more targeted you can make your lookup.  For example, in addition to the `error_type` field/column in the example above, you could make even be `"error_category": "disk", "error_type": "quota"` or somesuch.

The more structure you have in your log messages, the more your parsing/searching systems (such as `fluentd`, `elasticsearch`, `kibana`) can take advantage of that structure, and perform their tasks with greater speed and less CPU/memory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Want to add that it's not only about speed and efficiency. Relevance of search results will be a lot higher when using structured logging and thus "structured queries". Without that searching for any words that occur in different contexts will give you tons of irrelevant hits.

Comment: +1 from me too, I think this nails it. Added a slightly different formulation below, to expand on the case of event types as well.

Answer (score 10):

You won't find much benefit from structured logging when your app creates a few hundred log messages per day. You definitely will when you have a few hundred log messages per second coming from many different deployed apps.

Related, the setup where log messages end up in [the ELK Stack](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack) is also appropriate for scale where logging to SQL becomes a bottleneck.

I have seen the setup of "basic logging and searching" with SQL `select .. like` and regexps pushed to its limits where it falls apart - there are false positives, omissions, horrible filter code with knwon bugs that's hard to maintain and no-one wants to touch, new log messages that don't follow the filter's assumptions, reluctance to touch logging statements in code lest they break reports, etc.

So several software packages are emerging to deal with this problem in a better way. There is Serilog, I hear that the [NLog team is looking at it](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1376), and we wrote [`StructuredLogging.Json` for Nlog](https://github.com/justeat/NLog.StructuredLogging.Json#best-practices), I also see that the new [ASP.Net core logging abstractions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging) "make it possible for logging providers to implement ... structured logging".

An example with StructuredLogging. You log to an NLog logger like this:

```
logger.ExtendedError("Order send failed", new { OrderId = 1234, RestaurantId = 4567 } );
```

This structured data goes to kibana. The value `1234` is stored in the `OrderId` field of the log entry. You can then search using kibana query syntax for e.g. all log entries where `@LogType:nlog AND Level:Error AND OrderId:1234`.

`Message` and `OrderId` are now just fields that can be searched for exact or inexact matches as you need, or aggregated for counts. This is powerful and flexible.

From the [StructuredLogging best practices](https://github.com/justeat/NLog.StructuredLogging.Json#best-practices):

> The message logged should be the same every time. It should be a
> constant string, not a string formatted to contain data values such as
> ids or quantities. Then it is easy to search for.
>
> The message logged
> should be distinct i.e. not the same as the message produced by an
> unrelated log statement. Then searching for it does not match
> unrelated things as well.